# When authoring a TypeScript library, will the library tsconfig be respected despite the consumer having different settings?

Tags: typescript

If you publish a TypeScript library with certain configuration that differ to the consumer, for example;

- You have set `strict: false` but the consumer has set `strict:true`
- You have listed `lib: ["DOM"]` but the consumer hasn't

There are two scenarios I can imagine:

- The developer consuming the library cnt+clicks through to inspect the type definition of your type
- The TypeScript compiler must traverse the library's exported type declarations to see if they make sense in the context of the consumers usage.

will the TypeScript compiler/language server show/consider your exported type signatures in the context of your `tsconfig.json` or will the consumer/developer see errors unless their local `tsconfig.json` is compatible with your library's settings?

EDIT:

To be clear, I am describing publishing type declaration files alongside the associated compiled JavaScript - not talking about publishing TypeScript sources.

Comment: In this scenario are you publishing the TS sources with a tsconfig, or publishing a JS bundle with an optional set of type definitions? The typical package manager model is the latter, even if the TS sources and tsconfig are available on GitHub.

Comment: I'm describing the latter. type declarations that perhaps depend on `lib: ["DOM"]` or other settings that, if different to the consumers settings and weren't declared, would not make sense to the consumer